# How to lock the first select dropdown in a dynamic dropdown and still get data from it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I'm working on a service request module of a photography website. The main idea is to choose a service in the first dropdown *(wedding, debut, etc)* and depending on the choice, a second dropdown would be chosen for the package (different prices and features per package). Choosing a package will then provide a text detailing the features of that said package as seen on the image below.

[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HevP.jpg)

Now there is a flaw that I don't know where to change. You see, in the image if I try to change the service, the second dropdown resets, but the text remains.

What I want now is to lock the first dropdown after choosing to avoid changing it when the second dropdown emerges. Then I would just provide a reset button that would reset the form (which I also need help).

This is my current code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrap">
    <select id="Service" title="" name="Service">
        <option value="" selected hidden>Choose Service ...</option>
        <option value="wedding">Wedding</option>
        <option value="debut">Debut</option>
        <option value="children-party">Children's Party</option>
    </select>

    <div class="first-level-select">
        <div class="wedding">
            <select class="second-level-select">
                <option value="" selected hidden>Choose package ...</option>
                <option value="wedding-package-1">Package 1</option>
                <option value="wedding-package-2">Package 2</option>
        </div>
        <div class="debut">
            <select class="second-level-select">
                <option value="" selected hidden>Choose package ...</option>
                <option value="debut-package-1">Package 1</option>
                <option value="debut-package-2">Package 2</option>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="second-level-container">
        <div class="wedding-package-1">
        Php 8,000 <br><br>
        Unlimited shots stored in DVD <br>
        Edited video with 2 sets of DVD <br>
        MTV 4 to 5 minutes (Highlight video)
        </div>
        <div class="wedding-package-2">
        Php 15,000 <br><br>
        Unlimited shots stored in DVD <br>
        Magazine type album (20 pages, 100 pictures) <br>
        Edited video with 2 sets of DVD  <br>
        MTV 4 to 5 minutes (Highlight video)
        </div>
    </div>
```

There's also a second level container text for debut packages but it is too long. You get the idea.

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#Service').bind('change', function() {
    var elements = $('div.first-level-select').children().hide(); // hide all the elements
    var value = $(this).val();

    if (value.length) { // if somethings' selected
        elements.filter('.' + value).show(); // show the ones we want
                }
        }).trigger('change');

$('.second-level-select').bind('change', function() {
        var elements = $('div.second-level-container').children().hide(); // hide all the elements
        var value = $(this).val();

    if (value.length) { // if somethings' selected
        elements.filter('.' + value).show(); // show the ones we want
               }
        }).trigger('change');
    });
```

The problem is whenever I try to add an onchange event in the select dropdown, this happens.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRrSH.jpg)

It also happened when I used *disabled* in one of the options in the dropdown (that's why I used hidden).

If anyone could help, it would be really appreciated. I was also wondering how to get inputs from the dropdowns to be thrown in the database for administrator approval. And is it also possible to throw other data that was not specifically in the dropdown, like the price of the package which is just shown in text but should be thrown to the database as an INT type?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, sorry, I don't quite get where is the errror? Do you want to still get data from first dropdown but unable to change selection or something different?

Comment: No, sir. I'll give an example. You can check the 'sample' image above. Suppose to say I chose a Wedding service. The wedding packages can be chosen in the next dropdown. Then I chose package 2. A text will then appear showing the details of that specific package. Now when I suddenly change the service during this time, if I change the service to a Debut service for example, the package dropdown will reset and will now show choices for debut packages. But the text for the wedding package 2 will remain. That's the error.

Comment: That's why I want to lock the service drop-down. In that way, I can bypass the bug. But when I do an onchange disabledrop, the whole system breaks, shown in the 'error' image.  The texts for the package details are shown without choosing anything.

Comment: I see. Well, it looks like it can be solved by my current level of knowledge, but perhaps can you send me an email? Comments are not enough here as I need a little more information as well as more space. :)

Comment: I will asap. Also I posted a similar but more detailed question. This is the link: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39923421/lock-the-first-dropdown-after-the-choice-is-made-and-insert-values-in-a-table-de) Please read to understand more since I thought I rushed this question yesterday. Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to hurry because I'm going off soon so I will only be able to respond tomorrow. :)